# Escaping characters in glob patterns in Git

Tags: git, shell

The following git command (which deletes all files that end in a ~) uses escape characters

```
git rm \*~
```

The rationale is that git uses it's own filename expansion in addition to the expansion used by the shell.

Does this mean the escape characters are a way to suppress the filename expansion done by the shell ?

Somehow I am not able to get a proper handle on this.

- Why does git use it's own filename expansion ? Is it because shell filename expansion could work in different ways in different shells/OS's
- If so, why not just suppress filename expansion at the shell level for git commands, and allow git to perform it's own semantics with glob patterns

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the escape character suppresses the file name expansion normally performed by the Unix shell. To answer the subquestions:

1. `git rm` implements its own expansion likely because the files might not be present in the checked-out directory. (Think of the situation where you first `rm *~`, and then remember that you also want to remove them from `git`.)
2. Using the backslash escape character (or wrapping the argument in quotes) does exactly that — suppresses file name expansion at the shell level. This cannot be done by `git` automatically because `git` doesn't control your shell, by the time it is executed, the expansion is already over. The expansion must be prevented by the shell itself or, more realistically, by the end user invoking `git` through the shell.

Comment: This is correct, but is missing the actual difference in the way git expands globs. Yes, the shell won't expand globs to files it doesn't have access to, but it is specifically not recursive by design. If you want the shell to expand a glob to a file in a subdirectory, you have to be explicit about it (e.g., `*/*`). git filename expansion is recursive by default, and if you want it to NOT expand to a file in a subdirectory, you have to be explicit about it (e.g., `/*`) . See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54536377/7936744).

Comment: @DeNovo Good point, I didn't know about the recursive behavior of git globbing when I was writing this answer.

Answer (score 3):

> Why does git use its own filename expansion?

@user4815162342's answer is missing a key reason to escape a glob metacharacter (e.g., `*`) from the shell:

git's filename expansion is recursive. Your shell's filename expansion is not. To confirm:

```
mkdir testA testA/testB
cd testA
touch test1.txt testB/test2.txt
git init
```

Now you have a directory structure and git repo to use to test recursive filename expansion. While in testA:

```
echo *.txt
# test1.txt
git add \*.txt
git status
# On branch master
#
# No commits yest
#
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git rm --cached <file>..." to unstage)
#
# new file:    test1.txt
# new file:    testB/test2.txt
```

You can see that filename expansion by the shell is not recursive, as `echo *.txt` only expanded to text file in the `testA` directory. If you had run `git add *.txt`, you would have only added `test1.txt`. On the other hand, filename expansion in git *is* recursive. When you run `git add \*.txt`, suppressing the glob metacharacter from the shell and allowing git to expand it, it expands to all `.txt` files in your repo, which includes subdirectories.